# Plugins not installing during platform add with ionic/cordova on ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When adding a platform in ionic with plugins already defined in `package.json` a random set of plugins is installed and referenced in `plugins/ios.json`.

As a concrete example, my `package.json` contains this:

```
cordovaPlugins: [
    "com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics",
    "com.ionic.keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion",
    "com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk",
    "nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
    "https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner"
]
```

On the first run, the `plugins/ios.json` contains:

```
com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics
com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk
com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
cordova-plugin-console
nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight
uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion
```

If I clear the platforms and plugins folder and re-add the platform, then on second run I get:

```
com.ionic.keyboard
com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk
cordova-plugin-console
cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight
uk.co.whiteoctober.cordova.appversion
```

and so on.

During the `ionic platform add ios` step I do see all the plugins being added; however occasionally the `Running command: /path/to/project/hooks/after_platform_add/010_install_plugins.js` step will not run.

Is there a reliable way to install the plugins?

I am using:

```
| What    | Version |
| :------ | :------ |
| node    | 0.10.39 |
| cordova | 5.1.1   |
| ionic   | 1.6.1   |
```

contents of `010_install_plugins.sh` as requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Install all plugins listed in package.json
 * https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/master/templates/hooks/after_platform_add/install_plugins.js
 */
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys');

var packageJSON = null;

try {
  packageJSON = require('../../package.json');
} catch(ex) {
  console.log('\nThere was an error fetching your package.json file.')
  console.log('\nPlease ensure a valid package.json is in the root of this project\n')
  return;
}

var cmd = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'cordova.cmd' : 'cordova';
// var script = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/cordova/bin', cmd);

packageJSON.cordovaPlugins = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins || [];
packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.forEach(function (plugin) {
  exec('cordova plugin add ' + plugin, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.puts(stdout);
  });
});
```

Which is the default with ionic.

Comment: can you please show 010_install_plugins.js

Comment: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console` ? u tried this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the bug was in Ionic itself.

The hook file was running all plugin installs asyncronously, meaning that files were being written to concurrently so changes were being lost.

I've submitted a pull request to `ionic-cli` to fix the issue [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/pull/517/files). The change was to replace:

```
 packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.forEach(function (plugin) {
   exec('cordova plugin add ' + plugin, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
     sys.puts(stdout);
   });
});
```

with:

```
function installNextPlugin() {
    var curPlugin = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.shift();
    if (curPlugin) {
        exec('cordova plugin add ' + curPlugin, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            sys.puts(stdout);
            sys.puts(stderr);
        })
            .on("exit", function(code) {
                if (code) {
                    console.log("'cordova plugin add " + curPlugin + "' failed with code '" + code + "'");
                    process.exit(code);
                } else {
                    installNextPlugin();
                }
            });
    }
}

installNextPlugin();
```

in `010_install_plugins.js`.

Comment: that is brilliant, this has been giving me so much trouble the last weeks, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something I ran into previously and perhaps you've already done it but it is worth a try: chmod +x 010_install_plugins.js

Comment: Thanks, but ionic created the hooks and made them executable for me.